# KnexJS giving different response

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

So I have a NodeJS+KnexJS setup on a PostgreSQL DB, and am using the `.whereRaw()` method so I can use a `CASE` statement in my `WHERE` clause.

The query was tested in my CLI before migrating to code.  Here is the code that is being used.

```
var qry = knex.select(....);  // ignore the select, not important.
qry.with('daspecs', function(qy) {
   qy.select('spec_id').from('drawings').where('uid', query.d);
}).whereRaw('CASE WHEN (select "spec_id" from "daspecs") IS NULL THEN true ELSE c.spec_id = (select "spec_id" from "daspecs") END');
```

The SQL that KnexJS is generating (output using `qry.toString()`) is correct, and I can even copy and paste this to my *psql* CLI and it returns the results I want (12 records), but for some wierd reason the KnexJS query seems to return a completely different set of results (1106 records).

Not sure where to go next, since KnexJS is giving me the right SQL, but seems like it's executing something else, and not sure how else to diagnose what it is actually doing (I've tried the `knex.on('query'...)` event).

Any alteration on the final SQL would result in an error (i've tested), so at the point of ruling out missing pieces.

Has anyone had any experience or issues with KnexJS saying one thing, but doing another, in particular, with the `whereRaw` command?

Comment: after turning on logging in PostgreSQL, seems that it too gets the right query and parameter.... so I'm starting to think this is not a KnexJS issue